# I am small yet Large, who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> I am small. I am large. 
>   You call it I name it, 
>   You name it I have it. 
>   Want to add it to me? 
>   You would need a lot of support.

Who am I?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are:

> A dictionary

**Clues:**

I am small. I am large.

> Dictionaries come in different sizes some small some large

You call it I name it,

> Dictionaries give concepts names

You name it I have it.

> If it has been named, an extensive dictionary will have it with its definition

Want to add it to me? 
You would need a lot of support.

> I'm assuming there is some committee or process that requires support from others to add new words to a dictionary

Comment: Maybe small/large = abridged/unabridged?

Comment: @APrough that is definitely one possible explanation of that hint

Comment: Another possible explanation I feel for small/large would be it contains a large amount of information in a small package.

Comment: The possessive its does not have an apostrophe.

Comment: @DavidConrad alright I fixed it